# how set up an array and load the contenta using silex and twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, silex

I am looking to load an array of text into a twig template using silex,

How would I go about this? Would I set the array up as standard below?

(basic example)

```
$users = array(
'Username' => array(
    1 => 'Mike',
    2 => 'Sam',
    3 => 'Charlotte'
  ),
);
```

Or would I create it using silex along the lines of:

(example taken from silex documentation)

```
$blogPosts = array(
1 => array(
    'date'      => '2011-03-29',
    'author'    => 'igorw',
    'title'     => 'Using Silex',
    'body'      => '...',
 ),
);

 $app->get('/blog', function () use ($blogPosts) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($blogPosts as $post) {
    $output .= $post['title'];
    $output .= '<br />';
}

   return $output;
});
```

If I were to do it like that how would I go about loading that information into a twig template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) require twig with composer

```
composer require twig/twig
```

2.) register twig to your app

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));
```

3.) use twig provider in your routes

```
$app->get('/blog', function ($name) use ($blogPosts) {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($blogPosts as $post) {
        $output .= $post['title'];
        $output .= '<br />';
    }
    return $app['twig']->render('blog.twig', array(
        'output' => $output,
    ));
});
```

4.) use twig to display the output in your `__DIR__ . '/views/blog.twig'`

```
{{ output }}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've ended up with the error variable output does not exist in my twig file